# Android 10 - Using PackageManager to install new version of apk instead of Intents doesn't really work

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-10.0

The way my apk updates currently is through the new apk installing itself over the old one(while not overwriting the local database or settings).

So since Android 10(API 29) `ACTION_VIEW` was deprecated so this doesn't really work anymore:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
//output file is the apk downloaded earlier
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(outputFile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

Following different answers I've found over the internet I need to start using PackageInstaller instead. Looking at the demo found in the Android docs I get to this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(PSMentorActivity.this,InstallApkSessionApi.class);
intent.putExtra("apkFile",outputFile);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

Where InstallApkSessionApi contains a button that when pressed should start the install window:

```
PackageInstaller packageInstaller = getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
PackageInstaller.SessionParams params = new 
    PackageInstaller.SessionParams(PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL);
int sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(params);
session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId);
addApkToInstallSession(file, session);
// Create an install status receiver.
Context context = InstallApkSessionApi.this;
Intent intent = new Intent(context, InstallApkSessionApi.class);
intent.setAction(PACKAGE_INSTALLED_ACTION);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
IntentSender statusReceiver = pendingIntent.getIntentSender();
// Commit the session (this will start the installation workflow).
session.commit(statusReceiver);
```

Simple enough, albeit more complicated compared to the past. The response I get in onNewIntent is always:

```
 case PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE:
              Toast.makeText(this, "Install failed!10 " + status + ", " + message,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              break;
```

where the status and message take the following values: `status=1, message= "INSTALL_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR: Permission denied"`.

So I assumed it was a problem with permissions. I already had permissions in place over reading and writing to storage. Other related permissions are: `INSTALL_PACKAGES` and `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` which I cannot use due to the first not being intended for third party uses and the latter being signature level.

Is there something I am terribly missing or is there not a way for me to update my Apk without going through google play?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Math clearly had an impact in your life :D

Comment: positive, negative, who knows. been visiting this place for three years. First time I run into a problem I can't find the solution to. Glad to be here and I hope my questions will be few.

Comment: well at least your question is decent, that's a welcome change these days for new contributors - hope you find an answer

Comment: [This sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/tree/vFINAL/AppInstaller) demonstrates how to use `PackageInstaller`, and it works fine on Android 10. Your question does not show `addApkToInstallSession()`, which may be where your problem lies.

Comment: That is in Kotlin. There is an app demo which I've found but initially failed to adapt due to somehow failing handling the files correct. I still don't understand but I will figure it out. My addApkToInstallSession() was exactly as the one from the demo I've found(the one in Java). My outputFile which I was sending to the addApk was definitely there because when I tested the update on an older Android it did work.

Comment: I will explain my situation in a better way in a reply to this thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've faced the same issue and tried the same way(PackageInstaller) just like you did. It doesn't work. 
So, here is a solution for you,

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29){
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
       intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(outputFile));
       intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
       startActivity(intent);   
}else{
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      //output file is the apk downloaded earlier
      intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(outputFile), "application/vnd.android.package- 
      archive");
      startActivity(intent);
}
```

I have tested in Android 10 (Google Pixel 2, One+7, Samsung s10) it's working fine. If you are still facing any problem please let me know.
**Note:** *Your version code must be greater than the old one.*

Comment: It throws me a "No Activity found to handle Intent" and crashes with no success. Tested on Android 10 Emulator and on Xiaomi MI 9 T Pro. Is there something I need to add to the manifest?

Comment: Yeah, after checking the Android Documentation, it seems that this constant was also deprecated in 29. The documentation page even recommends using PackageInstaller which I've tried using to no success. It also specifies that anything targeting more than 25 will require REQUIRE_INSTALL_PACKAGES, a signature level permission.

Comment: Did you debug and check file path which you are passing in Uri.fromFile(path)?  This is what I did in my case "Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileProvider", file);".

Comment: How do you define that provider in the manifest file? I used to save the apk then call Uri.fromFile(outputFile)).

Comment: <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="package_name.fileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>

Comment: This is how my filepaths file looks   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
    <external-path
        path="Android/data/com.jas.digitalkyats/"
        name="files_root" />
    <external-path
        path="."
        name="external_storage_root" />
</paths>

Comment: Ok so I don't really understand why is there a need for a provider and how does it work. But it does make it work. The way I was treating files before 29 doesn't work anymore apparently and that is what gave me errors. I would kill for some more specific errors. Even PackageManager works now which I will move on to later. I will post my solutions in a separate comment and I will flag your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 5):

So after help and some more searching the great internet, I've been able to make both methods work for me. I still don't really understand what causes the problem. Previously I was creating the Uri used in the intent from the file directly with `Uri.fromFile(file)`. This works for anything under Android 10. The new way I handle this is by using a provider and getting the file using that.

1. Current method, to be used for a while until I can properly implement PackageManager installation(still have some issues to fix).

```
Uri urlapk = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".fileProvider",outputFile);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(urlapk, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(intent);
```

2. Using PackageManager just as specified in my question with the following difference (the inputStream is now being build from an Uri):

```
private void addApkToInstallSession(Uri uri, PackageInstaller.Session session)
            throws IOException {
        try (OutputStream packageInSession = session.openWrite("package", 0, -1);
             InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];

            int n;
            while ((n = is.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                packageInSession.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
        }
}
```

The main problem I have with PackageManager is that it closes my app while it installs providing no default feedback to the user. So I guess I will have to "make" that feedback. I will move on to PackageManager as ACTION_VIEW is deprecated for apks.

Comment: Hi. Your case is exactly like mine. I use api 24 and higher. Under 24 `Uri.fromFile(file)` was working but not under 29. With `ContentProvider` it works everywhere.

Comment: I also implemented a similar solution like this using package installer to install apk in COSU app, the thing is, it is working fine below android 10, and in android 10 I used the above code but the app is not updating instead it's getting restarts.